# Criar uma lista com os ultimos videos de um canal do youtube com o API V3

Tags: php, youtube, google-api

Eu tenho um código que pega os últimos vídeos de um canal e posta as miniaturas deles para ser executado em um popup (com jquery, essa parte funciona bem).

O código é esse:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    $feedURL = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/{- USER ID -}/uploads?max-results=50';
    $sxml = simplexml_load_file($feedURL);
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($sxml->entry as $entry):
        $media = $entry->children('media', true);
    $watch = (string)$media->group->player->attributes()->url;
    $thumbnail = (string)$media->group->thumbnail[0]->attributes()->url;
    $right_thumbnail = substr_replace($thumbnail, 'mqdefault', -5, -4);
?>

<li class="thumb-video">
    <a data-link="<?php echo $watch; ?>" id="play-zg-<?= $i; ?>" class="watch-the-video transition-3s">
        <img class="play-button transition-2s" src="<?= $directory_img; ?>/play-yt-icon.png">
        <img src="<?php echo $right_thumbnail;?>" alt="<?php echo $media->group->title; ?>" />
    </a>
</li>

<?php $i++; if($i == 2) { break; }; endforeach; ?>
```

Este código funcionava muito bem até o API do google mudar da versão 2 para a versão 3.

O problema é que agora eu não consigo adaptar os requerimentos da nova versão do API ao código, visto que eu não entendo nada sobre isso =/

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Desde já, agradeço =)

Script no header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```